# Outputting Shiny (non-ggplot) plot to PDF

Tags: r, shiny, knitr

Is there a method to output (UI end) Shiny plots to PDF for the app user to download?  I've tried various methods similar to those involving ggplot, but it seems `downloadHandler` can't operate in this way.  For example the following just produces broken PDF's that don't open.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(downloadButton('foo')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    plotInput = reactive({
      plot(1:10)
    })
    output$foo = downloadHandler(
      filename = 'test.pdf',
      content = function(file) {
        plotInput()
        dev.copy2pdf(file = file, width=12, height=8, out.type="pdf")
      })
  }
))
```

Very grateful for assistance.

Comment: For reference, @Victorp's method below fails when hosted at [shinyapps.io](https://geotheory.shinyapps.io/pdf_test/) with `Error: can only print from a screen device`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved.  The plot should be saved locally with `pdf()`, not the screen device (as with `dev.copy2pdf`).  Here's a working example: `shiny::runGist('d8d4a14542c0b9d32786')`.  For a nice basic model try:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {

        plotInput <- reactive({
            if(input$returnpdf){
                pdf("plot.pdf", width=as.numeric(input$w), height=as.numeric(input$h))
                plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
                dev.off()
            }
            plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
        })

        output$myplot <- renderPlot({ plotInput() })
        output$pdflink <- downloadHandler(
            filename <- "myplot.pdf",
            content <- function(file) {
                file.copy("plot.pdf", file)
            }
        )
    }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Output to PDF"),
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput('returnpdf', 'output pdf?', FALSE),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.returnpdf == true",
            strong("PDF size (inches):"),
            sliderInput(inputId="w", label = "width:", min=3, max=20, value=8, width=100, ticks=F),
            sliderInput(inputId="h", label = "height:", min=3, max=20, value=6, width=100, ticks=F),
            br(),
            downloadLink('pdflink')
        )
    ),
    mainPanel({ mainPanel(plotOutput("myplot")) })
)
```

Answer (score 3):

(Hello), just use `pdf` :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(downloadButton('foo')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    plotInput = reactive({
      plot(1:10)
    })
    output$foo = downloadHandler(
      filename = 'test.pdf',
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file = file, width=12, height=8)
        plotInput()
        dev.off()
      })
  }
))
```

EDIT : I don't know... It's weird. A workaround is to use `dev.copy2pdf` like you did in the first place but in the `reactive` function instead `downloadHandler` :

```
## server.R
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    plotInput <- reactive({plot(rnorm(1000))
                           dev.copy2pdf(file = "plot.pdf")
                           })
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({ plotInput() })
    output$foo <- downloadHandler(
      filename <- "plot.pdf",
      content <- function(file) {
        file.copy("plot.pdf", file)
      })
  }
)
```

Comment: Yes sorry Victorp I need to reopen this as the solution is Windows-specific, and also it fails for apps hosted at `shinyapps.io`.

Comment: No problem, i'm curious about the answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding `contentType = "application/pdf"` as an argument to downloadHandler?

Comment: Cracked it - see the other answer

Comment: How can I use this with knitr to create a pdf with a simple ggvis plot (through latex or rmarkdown)?